# Best way to Find Time and Distance Between List of Points in Python/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-maps-api-3

So, I'm relatively new to Python and programming in generally and learning along the way.

I'm have trouble just processing a massive list of points that doesn't return a matrix. Essentially just reiterating each row in excel. I've been trying to put together what I've found online, but I'm not looking for every permutation of origin point and destination point as its too much.

Using the distance_matrix function but it says returns matrix. https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html

Here's kind of where I'm at (partial code):

```
def Google_drive_time(o, d, departure_time
                      ,model, mode, 
                      avoid=False
                      ):
   def make_chunks(l, n):
        for i in range(0, len(l), n):
            yield l[i:i + n]

    assert (type(o) == tuple and len(o) == 2 and isinstance(o[0], float) 
        and isinstance(o[1], float))
    
    models = {'optimistic','best_guess','pessimistic'}
    if model not in models:
        raise ValueError("results: model must be one of %r." % models)

mychunks = list(make_chunks(d, 25))
    google_times, google_distances = [], []
    for chunk in mychunks:
        result = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins=o,
                                       destinations=chunk
                                       ,mode=mode
                                       ,avoid=avoid
                                       ,units='imperial'
                                       ,traffic_model=model
                                       ,departure_time=departure_time)
```

Input from excel and into Dataframe
enter code here

```
def extract_combine_input_mix(inputfile):
    import itertools
    
    times = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='Times')
    origins = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='Origins')
    destinations = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheet_name='Destinations')
    
    #Combine key values from each input
    days=times['Time: Day of Week'].dropna().unique().astype(int)
    hours=times['Time: Hour'].dropna().unique().astype(int)
    minutes=times['Time: Minute'].dropna().unique().astype(int)
    origins_list=origins['Origin']
    destinations_list=destinations['Destination']
    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(origins_list,destinations_list,days,hours,minutes)),\
                      columns=['Origin','Destination','Time: Day of Week','Time: Hour','Time: Minute'])
    
    df=pd.merge(df,origins,on='Origin',how='left')
    df=pd.merge(df,destinations,on='Destination',how='left')
    
    return df


df=extract_combine_input_mix(input_file)
columns = df.columns.values.tolist()

df['origin'] = list(zip(df['Origin Latitude'], df['Origin Longitude']))
df['destination'] = list(zip(df['Destination Latitude'], df['Destination Longitude']))
df['time'] = list(zip(df['Time: Day of Week'], df['Time: Hour'], df['Time: Minute']))
```

f

Comment: Please explain more about your current output and how it's not what you're aiming for.

Comment: @Driftr95 So the current output gives all combinations of origin and destination points. I don't need every combination and its too large of an output. I have a defined set of origin and destination points that are listed together in rows in excel, I was looking for it to process that.